# Duplicate code: How to find and remove with tools

Tags: duplicates, refactoring, code-duplication

I am managing a group of three interns working on a php project. They seem to be not good at refactoring and are using duplicate code in multiple places. I am looking for a tool which I can use to find this duplicate code so I can show them.

This would make my job easier, and the project more elegant and less prone to errors. Any leads?

Comment: I think it's a good idea to teach your interns code reuse and stuffs like object oriented programming and design.

Comment: You can get better duplicate detection if you choose a clone detector that understands the language you are coding in.  Which language are you using?

Answer (score 6):

PMD is a good tool to find code duplication. Here is a [link to the site](https://pmd.github.io/).

Comment: Oldies, goldies. Wanted to find cross-project code duplication, copied all relevant code to a temp. dir., downloaded PMD and ran ./bin/run.sh cpd --minimum-tokens 100 --files /tmp/tmpsrc . Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

See our [CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone) tool.  It finds duplicate code across large software systems, using compiler-accurate parsing to find matches guided by the language syntax (AST matching), ignoring changes in whitespace and linebreaks.  It will find exact duplicates, and near-miss duplicates.  For near-duplicates, its reports the differences in the near-misses as parameters; it almost tells you how to code a replacement subroutine for the clones.

CloneDR operates on a variety of languages: C, C++, C#, COBOL, EGL, Java, JavaScript, PHP, Python and many more.
Example detection reports for each of these can be found at the link.

Answer (score 0):

I like [CCFinderX](http://www.ccfinder.net/) a lot, but it is abandonware.